# pandas-ta in pycharm custom strategy from example library not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning to use pandas-ta
I installed pandas and pandas-ta from Settings/interpreter/'+' in PyCharm, (install success)
I tried to run the basic instructions from example library and it generates multiple log failures:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 288, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\PycharmProjects\TradingBOT\test2.py", line 38, in <module>
    df.ta.strategy(CustomStrategy)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\TradingBOT\lib\site-packages\pandas_ta\core.py", line 725, in strategy
    with Pool(self.cores) as pool:
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Code is copy-paste from source github:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta

df = pd.DataFrame() # Empty DataFrame

# Load data
df = df.ta.ticker("aapl")

# print(df)
# VWAP requires the DataFrame index to be a DatetimeIndex.
# Replace "datetime" with the appropriate column from your DataFrame
# df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]), inplace=True)

# Calculate Returns and append to the df DataFrame
df.ta.log_return(cumulative=True, append=True)
df.ta.percent_return(cumulative=True, append=True)

# New Columns with results
df.columns

# Take a peek
df.tail()

# Create your own Custom Strategy
CustomStrategy = ta.Strategy(
    name="Momo and Volatility",
    description="SMA 50,200, BBANDS, RSI, MACD and Volume SMA 20",
    ta=[
        {"kind": "sma", "length": 50},
        {"kind": "sma", "length": 200},
        {"kind": "bbands", "length": 20},
        {"kind": "rsi"},
        {"kind": "macd", "fast": 8, "slow": 21},
        {"kind": "sma", "close": "volume", "length": 20, "prefix": "VOLUME"},
    ]
)
# To run your "Custom Strategy"
df.ta.strategy(CustomStrategy)
```

I tried with this line of code:

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]), inplace=True)
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\TradingBOT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\PycharmProjects\TradingBOT\test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]), inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\TradingBOT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\TradingBOT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Date'
```

but df index is 'Date'

```
C:\Users\Pol87\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\TradingBOT\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Pol87\PycharmProjects\TradingBOT\test2.py 
                                 Open        High  ...  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                               ...                         
1980-12-12 00:00:00-05:00    0.100764    0.101203  ...        0.0           0.0
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Judging from the first traceback you're somehow mixing Python 3.9 and 3.10?

Comment: And please don't ask the same question multiple times ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670917/pandas-ta-example-on-documentation-not-workin) seems to be essentially the same).

Answer (score 0):

Strategies in pandas-ta almost always use multithreading.  Code that creates child processes in python should only run in the main program.  So if you protect your code with the usual:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

then multithreading will work properly.